# How to sort values in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I have some doubts. I get some result

```
poz = positiv[positiv["number"]>0].head(10)
poz
```

I got the output:

```
    number
abnormal    16
abolish 5
abominable  5
abomination 4
abort   1
aborted 6
abrasive    1
abrupt  6
abruptly    284
absence 10
```

But my result is alphabetical, how to sort so that it shows the most frequently used words. I tried using pd.nlargest but the result was the same as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `sort_values`

```
poz = poz.sort_values('number',ascending=False).head(10)
```

Comment: not helped. poz.sort_values(by='number').plot.barh i have it and show only word startwith a

Comment: @whyimnotwhy sort then head